# Cannot get this checkbox to build?

Tags: ios, swift, checkbox

[image]

I tried to fix other errors so it may look tad different but this is the best i could do.

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() { super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    Box49.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "UnCheckBox"), for: .normal)
    Box49.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "CheckBox"), for: .selected)

    Box50.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "UnCheckBox"), for: .normal)
    Box50.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "CheckBox"), for: .selected)

    Box51.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "UnCheckBox"), for: .normal)
    Box51.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "CheckBox"), for: .selected)

}

@IBAction func Box49(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !(sender as AnyObject).isSelected
}


@IBAction func Box50(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !(sender as AnyObject).isSelected
}


@IBAction func Box51(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !(sender as AnyObject).isSelected
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide way more information.

How is it wired, (do a double check for the wiring btw it might be that you have some old wires still in there). We also cannot see the error.

So your question is way too vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to create 3 outlet of button because you are currently setting image to button action, So either set both selected and normal image in your interface builder or create 3 button outlet like below.

```
@IBOutlet var box49: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var box50: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var box51: UIButton!
```

Now set the image to Button in either viewDidLoad or `viewDidAppear` not in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` also there is no need to cast sender to `AnyObject` to access `isSelected` property because sender type is `UIButton` and so you can directly access `isSelected` property.

```
var BoxOFF = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "UnCheckBox")
var BoxON = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "CheckBox") 
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
     box49.setImage(BoxOFF, for: .normal)
     box49.setImage(BoxON, for: .selected)

     box50.setImage(BoxOFF, for: .normal)
     box50.setImage(BoxON, for: .selected)

     box51.setImage(BoxOFF, for: .normal)
     box51.setImage(BoxON, for: .selected)
}
```

And now set your button action this way.

```
@IBAction func Box49(_ sender: Button) {
     sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}

@IBAction func Box50(_ sender: Button) {
     sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}

@IBAction func Box51(_ sender: Button) {
     sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```

Comment: Error: Value of type '(UIButton) -> ()' has no member 'setImage'

Comment: @DanielG Add the declaration of your buttons Box49, Box50 and Box51?

Comment: how exactly? sorry i am new

Comment: @DanielG Show the code of declaration of your 3 buttons.

Comment: What i have posted is everything i have written into Xcode. I'm not sure what you mean by show

Comment: although i have added : 

var BoxOFF = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "UnCheckBox")
var BoxON = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "CheckBox")

Comment: @DanielG I'm asking is all 3 buttons are your outlet button means it is connected with controller. Show the declaration line `var Box51` ?

Comment: i have no outlets, only actions. also I'm not sure how to declare, i haven't done that

Comment: @DanielG Then how you are able to access this `Box49` and other 2 buttons?

Comment: @DanielG Check my edited answer the problem is you are trying to set image to button action, You need to create button outlet and use that outlet to set image.

Comment: @DanielG Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 1):

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
 {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
 }
```

The above method is called when there is low memory and you need to release any resources.

So you need to add the code from the above method into `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`.

So replace the code as below:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
     Box49.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "UnCheckBox"), for: .normal)
    Box49.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "CheckBox"), for: .selected)

    Box50.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "UnCheckBox"), for: .normal)
    Box50.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "CheckBox"), for: .selected)

    Box51.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "UnCheckBox"), for: .normal)
    Box51.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "CheckBox"), for: .selected)

}
```

One another improvement is replace your code

```
sender.isSelected = !(sender as AnyObject).isSelected
```

with

```
sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
```